# Godot fails to correctly add children

Tags: godot

I have a node structure as

```
-Control
    Buttons (A Control node)
    Sprite
```

In the root node, I have a script which is meant to  add `50` buttons to the 2nd Control node.Well its not working at all ie it does not display any button at all but when I output`print(get_node("buttons.get_children()))` it gives me this:

```
[[Button:1142]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362], [Button:1367]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362], [Button:1367], [Button:1372]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362], [Button:1367], [Button:1372], [Button:1377]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362], [Button:1367], [Button:1372], [Button:1377], [Button:1382]]
[[Button:1142], [Button:1147], [Button:1152], [Button:1157], [Button:1162], [Button:1167], [Button:1172], [Button:1177], [Button:1182], [Button:1187], [Button:1192], [Button:1197], [Button:1202], [Button:1207], [Button:1212], [Button:1217], [Button:1222], [Button:1227], [Button:1232], [Button:1237], [Button:1242], [Button:1247], [Button:1252], [Button:1257], [Button:1262], [Button:1267], [Button:1272], [Button:1277], [Button:1282], [Button:1287], [Button:1292], [Button:1297], [Button:1302], [Button:1307], [Button:1312], [Button:1317], [Button:1322], [Button:1327], [Button:1332], [Button:1337], [Button:1342], [Button:1347], [Button:1352], [Button:1357], [Button:1362], [Button:1367], [Button:1372], [Button:1377], [Button:1382], [Button:1387]]
```

Yet it shows no button on the screen.I am sure that `globals.CURRENT_LEVEL` is et to `50`

Here is my code:

```
extends Control

var CURRENT_HIGHEST_LEVEL = globals.CURRENT_LEVEL
#onready var level_buttons = buttons.get_children()
var button_init_pos  = Vector2(100,100)
# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
onready var buttons = get_node("Buttons")
func _ready():
    print(buttons)
    print(CURRENT_HIGHEST_LEVEL)
    var i =1
    for i in range(CURRENT_HIGHEST_LEVEL+1):
        if i >0:
            var button = Button.new()
            var button_sprite = Sprite.new()
            button_sprite.texture = load("res://assets/button ("+str(i)+").png")
            button.add_child(button_sprite)
            buttons.add_child(button)
            print(buttons.get_children())
            if i == 1:
                button.set_position(button_init_pos)
            else:
                var prev_button =  buttons.get_child(i -1)
                button.set_position(Vector2(prev_button.get_position().x + 100, button_init_pos.y))



#           print("The level chooser button at : "+str(i)+" has position :"+str(buttons.get_child(i).get_position()))
```

Comment: For the future, while the game is running you can check the godot scene tree and switch to the "remote tree" view to inspect in real time the current active nodes.

Comment: Did you check the size of the button? I am not sure if a control element does resize itself if a child sprite is added